My script prevent me to automate installation of google app
Error running installer for D:\\New Installer\\ChromeSetup.exe: Command '\['D:\\New Installer\\ChromeSetup.exe', '/silent /install'\]' returned non-zero exit status 2147942487.

I try to work on automate installing apps from my pendrive to multiple of laptop. I can install other apps except chrome and firefox. But firefox does not show an error only chrome that show error
"Google Chrome": {
"source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
"installer": "ChromeSetup.exe",
"silent_flag": "/quiet",
"is_zip": False
}

im try to change the silent flag but i guess it does not work.
Here are my code:
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import zipfile
 
# Define the pendrive's main folder path
PENDRIVE_PATH = r"D:\New Installer"

# Target path on the laptop where apps will be installed
TARGET_PATH = os.path.join(os.environ["PROGRAMFILES"], "PortableApps")

# List of apps with their setup executables and optional silent flags
apps = {
    "7-Zip": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "7z2201-x64.exe",
        "silent_flag": "/S",
        "is_zip": False
    },
    "Adobe Reader": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "AcroRdrDC1901220036_en_US.exe",
        "silent_flag": "/sAll",
        "is_zip": False
    },
    "Google Chrome": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "ChromeSetup.exe",
        "silent_flag": "/quiet",
        "is_zip": False
    },
    "End User Software": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "End_user.msi",
        "silent_flag": "/quiet",
        "is_zip": False
    },
    "Mozilla Firefox": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "Firefox Installer.exe",
        "silent_flag": "/S",
        "is_zip": False
    },
    "Java Runtime Environment": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "JavaSetup8u351.exe",
        "silent_flag": "/s",
        "is_zip": False
    },
    "VLC Media Player": {
        "source": PENDRIVE_PATH,
        "installer": "vlc-3.0.18-win64.exe",
        "silent_flag": "/S",
        "is_zip": False
    }
}

# Function to copy files from pendrive to laptop
def copy_app_files(app_name, source_path, dest_path):
    if not os.path.exists(dest_path):
        os.makedirs(dest_path)
    shutil.copytree(source_path, dest_path, dirs_exist_ok=True)
    print(f"Copied {app_name} files to {dest_path}")

# Function to run the installer if needed
def run_installer(installer_path, silent_flag=None):
    try:
        # Check if the file is an .msi installer
        if installer_path.endswith(".msi"):
            command = ["msiexec", "/i", installer_path]
            if silent_flag:
                command.append(silent_flag)
        else:
            command = [installer_path]
            if silent_flag:
                command.append(silent_flag)

        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Ran installer for {installer_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error running installer for {installer_path}: {e}")

# Function to extract zip files if needed
def extract_zip(zip_path, extract_to):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(extract_to)
    print(f"Extracted {zip_path} to {extract_to}")

# Main function to install apps
def install_apps():
    if not os.path.exists(TARGET_PATH):
        os.makedirs(TARGET_PATH)
        print(f"Created target directory at {TARGET_PATH}")
    
    for app_name, app_info in apps.items():
        source = app_info["source"]
        dest = os.path.join(TARGET_PATH, app_name)
        installer = os.path.join(source, app_info["installer"])

        # Debug: Print the paths being checked
        print(f"Looking for {app_name} at {source}")

        # Copy the app files to the laptop
        if os.path.exists(source):
            copy_app_files(app_name, source, dest)
        else:
            print(f"Source path for {app_name} not found: {source}")
            continue

        # Check if the app is a zip file
        if app_info.get("is_zip"):
            if os.path.exists(installer):
                extract_zip(installer, dest)
            else:
                print(f"Zip file not found for {app_name} at {installer}")
        else:
            # Run the installer if it's an executable
            if os.path.exists(installer):
                run_installer(installer, app_info.get("silent_flag"))
            else:
                print(f"Installer not found for {app_name} at {installer}")

    print("All applications installed successfully.")

# Run the main function when the script is executed directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    install_apps()


Why not use something like Ansible for this? Or why not Chocolatey or Scoop?
